# Executing function twice

Tags: javascript, c++, function, duktape

Okay, so basically I've got a long array of objects and I need to call a JavaScript function multiple times with the array as a parameter. I already got it working when recreating the list every time I call the function but the attempt to move the array to the top of the Duktape stack didn't work as expected. Maybe I'm on the completely wrong track ...

```
duk_context* ctx(duk_create_heap_default());

duk_push_c_function(ctx, nativePrint, DUK_VARARGS);
duk_put_global_string(ctx, "print");

/// Define the function the first time
duk_eval_string(ctx, "function func(entries, targetEntry) { print(targetEntry, JSON.stringify(entries)); return 404; }");
duk_get_global_string(ctx, "func");

/// Define lambdas to create the array
auto pushObject = [&] () {
    duk_idx_t obj_idx;

    obj_idx = duk_push_object(ctx);
    duk_push_int(ctx, 42);
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, obj_idx, "meaningOfLife");
};

auto pushArray = [&] () {
    duk_idx_t arr_idx;

    arr_idx = duk_push_array(ctx);
    pushObject();
    duk_put_prop_index(ctx, arr_idx, 0);
    pushObject();
    duk_put_prop_index(ctx, arr_idx, 1);

    return arr_idx;
};

/// Push the arguments
auto arr_idx = pushArray();
duk_push_number(ctx, 102);

/// Define lambda to call the function
auto processEntry = [&] () {
    if (duk_pcall(ctx, 2 /*nargs*/) != 0) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", duk_safe_to_string(ctx, -1));
    } else {
        if (duk_is_number(ctx, -1)) cout << "NumRes: " << duk_get_number(ctx, -1) << endl;
        else printf("Res: %s\n", duk_safe_to_string(ctx, -1));
    }

    duk_pop(ctx);

    cout << endl;
};

/// Calling the function the first time
processEntry();

/// Loading the function as the global string again
duk_eval_string(ctx, "function func(entries, targetEntry) { print(targetEntry, JSON.stringify(entries)); return 404; }");
duk_get_global_string(ctx, "func");

/// Attempt to move the array to the top and execute the function
/// Executing pushArray(); again works but not duk_swap_top(...);
// pushArray();
duk_swap_top(ctx, arr_idx);
duk_push_number(ctx, 444);
processEntry();
```

As you can see, at the very bottom I attempt to call `duk_swap_top(ctx, arr_idx)` in order to move the array to the top. Apparently, it does not do what I thought it would and instead returns **`TypeError: undefined not callable`**. When replacing that with another `pushArray();` it works as expected and both **102** and **444** gets printed out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're pushing an array and '102' to the value stack:

```
[ ... array 102 ]
```

You then call duk_pcall() which consumes the arguments (nargs=2) and pushes the result:

```
[ ... result ]
```

The result is then popped.  After the call the array is no longer in the value stack.

There are various ways to structure your code, but you could first register 'func' and create the array, and then use the following sequence for every call (including the first):

```
duk_get_global_string(ctx, "func");
duk_dup(ctx, arr_idx);  /* duplicate array reference */
duk_push_uint(ctx, 1234);  /* additional argument, varies? */
rc = duk_pcall(ctx, 2);
/* inspect result */
duk_pop(ctx);
```

This preserves the array at arr_idx between calls.